# How to get SQL queries from OfBiz's entity engine?

Tags: ofbiz

I have an `EntityCondition` and I want to get SQL from it. For example

```
EntityCondition: partyId = 'admin'
-> SQL:  party_id = 'admin'
```

I have tried to find in OFBiz project, but I have not found anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, please be more specific. For the above, there is at least the entity you want to select missing.
For Party it would be:
SELECT * FROM PARTY WHERE PARTY_ID = 'admin';

Comment: @MichaelBrohl When we use EntityCondition#toString(), we will get `partyId = 'admin'`, but to query to database i must be `party_id` not `partyId`.

Answer (score 3):

There's a general rule in OFBiz: entities and fields are defined in CamelCase, like PartyAttribute or productId. Entities begin with an uppercase letter (like a Java class) and fields begin with a lowercase letter (like a Java class attribute).

An uppercase letter inside the entity or field is converted to "_[lowercase]".

So

```
EntityCondition: partyId = 'admin'
-> SQL:  party_id = 'admin'
```

A full select for entity PartyAttribute would be

```
SELECT * FROM PARTY_ATTRIBUTE WHERE PARTY_ID = 'admin'
```

You may try

```
makeWhereString(ModelEntity modelEntity, List<EntityConditionParam> entityConditionParams, DatasourceInfo datasourceInfo)
```

to achieve this programmatically, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: This is exactly way I did, still require code, thank for your help :)

Comment: Update my answer to give a hint to makeWhereString(ModelEntity modelEntity, List<EntityConditionParam> entityConditionParams, DatasourceInfo datasourceInfo)

Answer (score 2):

In

`\ofbiz_src\framework\entity\src\org\ofbiz\entity\datasource\GenericDAO.java` you will see something like (In Apache Ofbiz 13, it stand about in about line 808 or nearby)

```java
makeOffsetString(sqlBuffer, findOptions);
String sql = sqlBuffer.toString();
```

Add a line of code for printing query

```java
makeOffsetString(sqlBuffer, findOptions);
String sql = sqlBuffer.toString();
System.out.println("SQL query: >>>" + sql);
```

By this way, you just able see query with parameter `?`, you cannot see value of parameter `?` in real world, like HQL query log in Hibernate.

Comment: Thank for late answer. Please check zalo message!